# Limit Points of Shuffled Sequences and the Original Sequences

Tags: analysis

Prove that the set of limit-points of a shuffled sequence $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$ is exactly the union of the set of limit-points of $\{x_j\}$ and the set of limit-points of $\{y_i\}$. Is the same true if the shuffling is not regular?

In proving that a limit point in the shuffled sequence is a limit point in the union of the two original sequences, would we just use casework in some infinite sequence? (i.e. looking at the indices of the shuffled sequence and seeing which combination of an infinite number of points would put it into a limit-point of the x sequence, y sequence, or both?)

Comment: I share your confusion.  Never having formally studied this, I am forced to rely on my intuition, which could easily be mistaken.  If you presume that a point is a limit point if and only if the point occurs infinitely often in the sequence, then one wonders what the relevance is of whether the shuffling is *regular*.  However, that is not the definition of a limit point.  A point can be a limit point if a subsequence converges to it, without ever hitting it.  For example $0$ is a limit point of $1,1,1/2,2,1/3,3,1/4,4,\cdots$.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, now you have to somehow consider how the limit of a convergent subsequence will be affected if there is regular shuffling, and if (instead) there is irregular shuffling.  My instinct is that this is the wrong time to try to re-invent the wheel.  I suspect that if this problem is from a book or class, then there have been previously solved problems, theorems, or worked examples that are relevant here.  I suggest that you find and focus on these previous results.